# Submiting a form when refreshed or back button id pressed with responce to confirmation from user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, form-submit, page-refresh

I am developing a quiz module. In the test page, when the user tries to refresh the page or  tries to go back, I should alert the user and if he further wishes to do so, I should submit the form.
This is my HTML form.

```
<form method="post" name="form1" id="form1" action="testdone.php" >
<?php 
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * from test WHERE id='".$recordid."'");
$record = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
for($i=1;$i <= $record['noofquestion'];$i++)
{
        $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM question WHERE id='".$questions[$i-1]."'");
        $ques= mysql_fetch_array($sql1);
        ?>
        <div class="col-xs-11 col-xs-offset-1">
        <?php echo "<p style=\"font-size:25px\">".$i.".".$ques['question']."</p><br>";?>
        <input type="radio" name="responce[<?php echo $i-1 ?>]" value="na" checked="checked" hidden="hidden">
        <input type="radio" name="responce[<?php echo $i-1 ?>]" value="a" required><font style="font-size:20px;" ><?php echo $ques['a']; ?></font>
        <input type="radio" name="responce[<?php echo $i-1 ?>]" value="b" required><font style="font-size:20px;"><?php echo $ques['b']; ?></font>
        <input type="radio" name="responce[<?php echo $i-1 ?>]" value="c" required><font style="font-size:20px;"><?php echo $ques['c']; ?></font>
        <input type="radio" name="responce[<?php echo $i-1 ?>]" value="d" required><font style="font-size:20px;"><?php echo $ques['d']; ?></font> 
        </div>
    <?php
       }
    ?><center><input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" name="submitbutton" id="submitbutton"></center>
</form>
```

And this is my script to detect reloading

```
<script>
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    $('#form1').submit();
    return true;
  };
</script>
```

**NOTE**: I also have a timer which submits the page after it ends.
This is my timer code.

```
 function CountDown(duration, display) {
        if (!isNaN(duration)) {
            var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;

          var interVal=  setInterval(function () {
                minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
                seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

                minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
                seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

                $(display).html("<b style=\"font-size:25px;\">Time left: " + minutes + "m : " + seconds + "s" + "</b>");
                if (--timer < 0) {
                    timer = duration;
                   SubmitFunction();
                   $('#display').empty();
                  clearInterval(interVal)
                }

                },1000);
        }
    }

    function SubmitFunction(){
        document.form1.submit(); 
        return false;
    }
CountDown(<?php echo $duration*60; ?>,$('#display'));
```

Currently my page does not submits at the end of timer by default(page asks me to whether stay or leave) and refreshing makes the timer to set to starting time, But prompts me when refersh or back button is pressed.
Someone help me out here!!! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't see anything in your code provided that would explain why it is prompting the user.  Are you testing in a jfiddle/codepen or something?  if you are posting to a different page, those sites will likely confirm page changes or refreshes.

Comment: @Steve the window.onbeforeunload = function() in the script will prompt the user when page is reloaded. I need to submit the form when user selects leave page in the prompt, but it simply refreshes it.